# How to sort big files?

Tags: sort

I have a PC with Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G640 @ 2.80 GHz and 8 GB of RAM. I am running Scientific Linux 6.5 on it with EXT3 filesystem.

On this setup, what is the fastest way I can do a `sort -u` on a 200 gigabyte file?

Should I split the file into smaller files (smaller than 8 GB), `sort -u` them, put them together, then split them again in a different size, `sort -u` again, etc.? Or are there any sorting scripts, programs that could handle files this big with my limited amount of RAM?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what happens when you try the command you posted. Do you run out of disk space? The command should work as long as you have enough free space on your `/tmp`.

Comment: `sort` does not work in RAM, it stores temp files in `/tmp`. RAM should not be the limiting factor. Please [edit] and answer my previous questions and also post the result of `df -h`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930044/how-could-the-unix-sort-command-sort-a-very-large-file

Comment: The chosen answer basically says what @terdon is saying, but also check out this one - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13025731/2801913. You will need GNU `parallel` for this I think rather than the moreutils `parallel` that is installed by default on some systems.

Comment: Also - http://blog.mafr.de/2010/05/23/sorting-large-files/

Comment: You could upload the file to Amazon S3, then spin up an Elastic Map Reduce job with a few hundred nodes to sort it!

Comment: What you describe - splitting sorting then merging and resorting is called a merge sort and it can be very fast because you can parallelise it.

Comment: `sort(1)` could run out of space on `/tmp`; if so, you can designate another area for temporary files with the environment variable `TMPDIR`, or flag `-T=<tmpdir>`

Comment: @MattH, GNU sort does that already with `--parallel=...`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

GNU `sort` (which is the default on most Linux systems), has a `--parallel` option. From http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html:

> ‘--parallel=n’
>
> Set the number of sorts run in parallel to n. By default, n is set to the number of available processors, but limited to 8, as there are diminishing performance gains after that. Note also that using n threads increases the memory usage by a factor of log n. Also see nproc invocation.

Since your cpu has 2 cores, you could do:

```
sort --parallel=2 -uo list-sorted.txt list.txt
```

It is better to specify the actual number of cores since there may appear to be more due to the processor having [hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).

You could also experiment with `nice` to influence the processor scheduling priority and `ionice` to influence I/O scheduling. You can increase the priority over other processes like this, I don't think this will give you large savings as they are usually better for making sure a background process doesn't use *too much* resources. Never-the-less you can combine them with something like:

```
nice -n -20 ionice -c2 -n7 sort --parallel=2 -uo list-sorted.txt list.txt
```

Note also that as [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120096/how-to-sort-big-files/120100#comment188976_120100) commented, using a single GNU sort command will be faster than any other method of breaking down the sorting as the algorithm is already optimised to handle large files. Anything else will likely just slow things down.

Comment: And you should note that calling `sort` directly is better than anything else you could cobble up. GNU sort is designed to cope well with files that are much larger than RAM.

Comment: The --parallel sort option does not work on my RH6.5 servers. Sort --version thinks it comes out of coreutils 8.4. Which version do I need to the the parallel version ?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/938558/sort-parallel-isnt-parallelizing – you may have to specify something like -S512M if you notice it's not actually parallelising.

Answer (score 58):

Using the `sort` command will probably be the fastest option.

But you'll probably want to fix the locale to C.

`sort -u` doesn't report unique lines, but one of each set of lines that sort the same. In the C locale, 2 different lines necessarily don't sort the same, but that's not the case in most UTF-8 based locales on GNU systems.

Also, using the C locale avoids the overhead of having to parse UTF-8 and processing complex sort orders so would improve performance dramatically.

So:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -u file
```

You can also improve performance by using a faster drive (or a different drive from the one where the input and/or output files are) for the temporary files (using `-T` or `$TMPDIR` environment variable), or by fiddling with the `-S` option supported by some `sort` implementations).

For some type of input or for slow storage, using the `--compress-program` option of GNU `sort` (for instance with `lzop`) might improve performance in addition to storage usage.

---

> **Now just a note for those objecting (rightly to some extent) that *it will not be the correct order***:
>
> I agree that as a human, I'd like to see *Stéphane* sort in between *Stefan* and *Stephanie*, but:
>
> - A *computer* would want *Stéphane* to sort after since `é` (at least when expressed as U+00E9) as a character or the bytes of its UTF-8 encoding sorts after (in terms of codepoint or byte value). That's a sort order that is very simple to implement and is a [strict total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_total_order) and has no surprise.
> - Your locale's sort order will likely not be satisfactory in many cases either even to a human. For example on my system with the default en_GB.utf8 locale:
>
>   - *Stéphane* and *Stéphane* (one with U+00E9, the other with eU+0301) don't sort the same:
>
>     ```
>     $ printf '%b\n' 'Ste\u0301phane' 'St\u00e9phane' | sort -u
>     Stéphane
>     Stéphane
>     ```
>   - but ③, ①, ② all sort the same (obviously a bug in those locale definitions¹):
>
>     ```
>     $ printf '%s\n' ③ ① ② | sort -u
>     ③
>     ```
>
>     Here, it's ③, but it could just as well have been ① or ②
>
> So IMO, chances are you always want `sort -u` with LC_ALL=C, if you want unique lines. And if you want that resulting list to be sorted in the user's sort order, pipe it to `sort` again:
>
> ```
> LC_ALL=C sort -u | sort
>
> LC_ALL=C sort | LC_ALL=C uniq -c | sort -k2
> ```

---

<sup>¹ **2019 edit**. the order of ① ② ③ ④ ⑤... has since been fixed in newer versions of the GNU libc, but as of 2.30, over 95% of characters still don't have a defined order, you can replace ① ② ③ ④ ⑤ with      for instance. Hopefully, GNU locales will eventually be fixed completely ([they will have to if they want to comply to the next revision of the standard](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1070)) and the problem will then be limited to user-defined locales</sup>

Comment: Yes. sorting file with 250000 lines the LC_ALL speeds things 8 times.

Comment: As a (strange) performance data point: sorting a 11G text file with LC_ALL=C takes about 3 minutes, w/o it did not finish even after 9h.

Comment: @miku, not so strange, `strcoll()` (comparing characters in a complex encoding using multi-pass human rules) is several orders of magnitude more difficult than `memcmp()` (comparing byte values without having to interpret them as characters)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a ready to use bash script for sorting TB scale data on a regular machine with couple of GB ram:  http://sgolconda.blogspot.com/2015/11/sort-very-large-dataset.html
It checks number of cores your machine as and uses all cores.
Can sort, numeric or string files.
Can be used to find unique records in TB scale data.

Comment: This is not a good suggestion.  The script is immensely bloated and splits the input file to sort the parts which the accepted answer points out isn't needed with GNU sort.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen while I can't attest to the practicality of that script, spreading temporary sortwork files across multiple IO channels is most certainly better than doing all the work in one IO channel.

Comment: Interesting.  Have you benchmarked it against gnu sort running multiple threads? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452570/4869