# Remove lines based on duplicates within one column without sort

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have large 3-column files (~10,000 lines) and I would like to remove lines when the contents of the third column of that line appear in the third column of another line. The files' sizes make sort a bit cumbersome, and I can't use something like the below code because the entire lines aren't identical; just the contents of column 3.

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' filename
```

Answer (score 51):

Just change your awk command to the column you want to remove duplicated lines based on that column (in your case third column):

```
awk '!seen[$3]++' filename
```

This command is telling `awk` which lines to print. The variable `$3` holds the entire contents of column 3 and square brackets are array access. So, for each third column of line in filename, the node of the array named `seen` is incremented and the line printed if the content of that node(column3) was not (`!`) previously set. By doing this, always the first lines (unique by the third column) will be kept.

Above will work if your columns in input file are delimited with Spaces/Tabs, if that is something else, you will need to tell it to awk with its `-F` option. So, for example if columns delimited with comma(`,`) and wants to remove lines base on third column, use the command as following:

```
awk -F',' '!seen[$3]++' filename
```

Answer (score 31):

`sort` command is already optimized to handle huge files. So, you could very well use the `sort` command on your file as,

```
sort -u -t' ' -k3,3 file
```

- `-u` - print only the unique lines.
- `-t` - specify the delimiter. Here in this example, I just use the space as delimiter.
- `-k3,3` - sort on 3rd field.

You could refer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120100/47538) answer which suggests that GNU sort is in fact the better approach for sorting big files. In your case, I think even without `-parallel`, you could achieve your end result without much of time delay.

Comment: Was about to comment snarkily that `-u` would only remove duplicate _lines_, not duplicate _keys_... but I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ramesh it does the job but sorting changes the sequence of lines that I guess not expected always.

Comment: @Ramesh-Why do we need -k3,3 instead of just  -k3?

Comment: @PhilCoulson - `-k3` would sort using the string starting with the 3rd key rather than sort ONLY using the 3rd key. Try `printf 'a b\na c\n' | sort -k1,1 -u` vs `printf 'a b\na c\n' | sort -k1 -u`.

Comment: @Bharat GNU sort has a `-s` option to handle that.

Comment: @Ramesh there's no indication in the question that using `-t' '` would be useful or even the right thing to do, it'd break if the input was tab-separated for example.