# Empty columns which were seen before

Tags: awk, macintosh, csv

I have a large CSV file and want to empty certain columns if they were seen before.

So I have (to illustrate my problem):

```
Category | Subcategory
---------+------------
foo      | bar
foo      | bar
foo      | foobar
foo      | foobar
```

And I want:

```
Category | Subcategory
---------+------------
foo      | bar
         | 
         | foobar
         |
```

The whole CSV is sorted (with `sort --strong -k 1,2`), so I just need a way to do my task with one column and can later use the same method with the other column.
Basically: delete every occurence of "foo" except the first.

It is similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171091/remove-lines-based-on-duplicates-within-one-column-without-sort), but I don't want to remove the complete line ..

I'm not sure how to do this, since I'm not that into awk.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Not really, I'm not a real awk guru ;)

Comment: you should try something before post questions and include your attempts, SO it is not code write resource.

Comment: Additionally, I assume that construction you're showing is just for illustration, right? Because that's definitely not a csv.

Comment: @Зелёный: Yes, you're right, sorry. ... and I forgot to ask a question :(

Comment: @HalosGhost: Yes, that's just for the illustration.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is usual task for print unique fild in `awk`

```
awk -F"[| ]+" -v OFS=" |" '
NR==1 {
    for (i=0;i<length($1);i++)
        blank=" " blank
}
{
    if (($1,$2) in b) 
        $2=""
    else 
        b[$1,$2]=1
    if ($1 in a) 
        $1=blank
    else 
        a[$1]=1
    print 
 }' large.csv
```