# How can I remove duplicated tags based on specific attribute name in an XML file?

Tags: text-processing, xml, uniq

How can I remove duplicate line based on "groupName" and keep the line with `directoryId="1"`?

```
<Group id="123" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="1" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" type="GROUP" directoryId="10100"/>
<Group id="456" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="0" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" type="GROUP" directoryId="1"/>
```

Comment: Update the question to include the information. You might want to add newlines to make it readable. Ideally you write (part of) your input, the desired output **and what you  have tried so far**.

Comment: with which language or tool?

Comment: What is the _specific_ criteria for choosing the one with directoryId = 1?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think `uniq` is necessarily the right tool for this, as it's meant for whitespace-separated or fixed-width files (apparent from its only two "column"-related options being `--skip-fields` and `--skip-chars`), while what you have here is XML-like data where neither the column widths are fixed nor are there any trivial single-character separators between columns (the values of `groupName` etc. could in principle contain whitespace).

I would instead use tools that are meant to deal with XML.

One option that avoids having to write a script yourself would be XPath-based filtering. How XPath can be used to filter for uniqueness can be understood from answers like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18451567/2748899) - the important syntax elements are the `following-sibling::` and `preceding-sibling::` axes. Command-line tools for evaluating XPath expressions can be found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15461737/2748899). Of the ones I've tried, the most easily-installed was `basex` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62634184/2748899)) so I'll use that in the following.

If I understood your question correctly, you want to reduce lines (XML elements) with the same `groupName` to just the last such line (or was there another reason for choosing the line with `directoryId="1"`?). For an XML document like this:

```xml
<Groups>
<Group id="123" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="1" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" type="GROUP" directoryId="10100"/>
<Group id="456" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="0" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" type="GROUP" directoryId="1"/>
<Groups>
```

where we had to wrap everything in a root element (`Groups`) to make it [well-formed XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document), this requirement can be achieved with the following XPath expression:

```
/Groups/Group[not(@groupName = following-sibling::Group/@groupName)]
```

`/Groups/Group` selects elements to return, which are then filtered using the expression in `[]`. `@` selects attributes and `following-sibling::` matches all subsequent sibling elements of the current one (cf. [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)).

Running this through `basex` yields the expected results:

```bsh
$ basex -i - '/Groups/Group[not(@groupName = following-sibling::Group/@groupName)]'

# [paste this into the terminal:]

<Groups>
<Group id="123" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="1" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" type="GROUP" directoryId="10100"/>
<Group id="456" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="0" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" type="GROUP" directoryId="1"/>
</Groups>

# [output:]

<Group id="456" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="0" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" type="GROUP" directoryId="1"/>
```

The downside compared to `uniq` is that `basex` will first read the entire XML document into memory, so for very large files exceeding the main memory size, this isn't viable. There are XML processors that [operate on XML in a streaming manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_XML), e.g. XSLT 3.0 has streaming transformations, so if you have to handle huge files, there is probably a way to do this using any XSLT 3.0 capable processor. But at that point it might be easier to just write your own small streaming parser by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the XML document is well formed, such as

```xml
<Groups>
<Group id="123" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="1" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" type="GROUP" directoryId="10100"/>
<Group id="456" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="0" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" type="GROUP" directoryId="1"/>
</Groups>
```

(I've just added a root node called `Groups`), then you may use `xq`, the XML parser wrapper around `jq`, from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/, like so:

```bsh
xq -x '.[].Group |= unique_by(."@groupName")' file.xml
```

This keeps only the unique `Group` nodes by their `groupName` attribute.  The first seen node for a value of the attribute will be kept.

The result of the above command when applied to the XML at the top:

```xml
<Groups>
  <Group id="123" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="1" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" type="GROUP" directoryId="10100"></Group>
</Groups>
```

To make sure that you get the one with the lowest `directoryID` attribute value, sort the nodes by this value first, before uniquifying the list:

```bsh
xq -x '.[].Group |= (sort_by(."@directoryId") | unique_by(."@groupName"))' file.xml
```

This would result in

```xml
<Groups>
  <Group id="456" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="0" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" type="GROUP" directoryId="1"></Group>
</Groups>
```

---

For reference, since `xq` is built on top of `jq`, the expression is actually applied to a JSON document translated from your XML document.  The modified JSON document is then translated back to XML.  The JSON document  that is modified, given the XML at the top of this answer, looks like this:

```json
{
  "Groups": {
    "Group": [
      {
        "@id": "123",
        "@groupName": "ABC",
        "@lowerGroupName": "abc",
        "@active": "1",
        "@local": "1",
        "@createdDate": "2017-08-21 09:28:30.581",
        "@updatedDate": "2017-08-21 09:28:30.581",
        "@type": "GROUP",
        "@directoryId": "10100"
      },
      {
        "@id": "456",
        "@groupName": "ABC",
        "@lowerGroupName": "abc",
        "@active": "1",
        "@local": "0",
        "@createdDate": "2017-08-21 09:28:30.634",
        "@updatedDate": "2017-08-21 09:28:30.634",
        "@type": "GROUP",
        "@directoryId": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Identify the line(s) with the identifier: `grep 'groupName="ABC"'`

From that you want to deselect the specific line with the exclusion criteria: `grep -v 'directoryId="1"'`

This will give you the lines to remove. Now we can force duplicate lines and specifically eliminate them:

```
grep 'groupName="ABC"' input-file | grep -v 'directoryId="1"' > to-remove
cat input-file to-remove | sort | uniq -u > output-file
```

If you want to clean everything up at the end you can add:

```
rm to-remove input-file
mv output-file input-file
```

**Warning** This will rearrange the contents of you input file. If you simply have a listing of entries without additional structure this solution should suffice.

Comment: There could theoretically be other nodes than `Group` nodes with those attributes. Also note that XML files may have newlines between attributes.

Comment: @Kusalananda - Very true, and in general I prefer an XSLT/XPath based solution. However, the original post hinted at something simpler. Without amplifying information, my solution does resolve the issue based on the admittedly limited information provided.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer ignoring the XML nature of the data, but only valid under the assumptions that a) this will be used as a "one-off" and not in a production workflow, b) the order of attributes is exactly the same for each line and c) there will never be any lines with whitespaces in the attributes before `groupName` (nor inside `groupName`'s own value):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171100/68864) shows how to use `awk` to filter out duplicates based on whitespace-separated fields. In your case, that would also be `awk '!seen[$3]++'`, as the `groupName` part is the third whitespace-separated column. However, if I understood it correctly, you want the *last* line of each "group of duplicates", not the first (which is what the `awk` one-liner above would give you). To achieve that, you can simply reverse the order of lines using `tac` before feeding them into `awk`, and then reverse them again afterwards to restore the original order:

```bsh
$ tac | awk '!seen[$3]++' | tac

# [paste this into the terminal:]

<Group id="123" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="1" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.581" type="GROUP" directoryId="10100"/>
<Group id="456" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="0" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" type="GROUP" directoryId="1"/>

# [output is:]

<Group id="456" groupName="ABC" lowerGroupName="abc" active="1" local="0" createdDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" updatedDate="2017-08-21 09:28:30.634" type="GROUP" directoryId="1"/>
```