# multicore equivalent for '| sort | uniq -c | sort -n' command

Tags: sort, parallelism

I would like to ask if there is a out of the box multicore equivalent for a  '| sort | uniq -c | sort -n' command?

I know that I can use [below](http://arnab.org/blog/quick-and-easy-multicore-sort) procedure

```
split -l5000000 data.tsv '_tmp';
ls -1 _tmp* | while read FILE; do sort $FILE -o $FILE & done;
sort -m _tmp* -o data.tsv.sorted
```

But it tastes a bit overhelming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GNU `sort` has a `--parallel` flag:

```
sort --parallel=8 data.tsv | uniq -c | sort --parallel=8 -n
```

This would use eight concurrent processes/threads to do each of the two sorting steps.  The `uniq -c` part will still be using a single process.

As Stéphane Chazelas points out in comments, the GNU implementation of `sort` is already parallelised (it's using POSIX threads), so modifying the number of concurrent threads is only needed if you want it to use more or fewer threads than what you have cores.

Note that the second `sort` will likely get much less data than the first, due to the `uniq` step, so it will be much quicker.

You may also (possibly) improve sorting speed by playing around with `--buffer-size=SIZE` and `--batch-size=NMERGE`.  See the `sort` manual.

To further speed the sorting up, make sure that `sort` writes its temporary files to a fast filesystem (if you have several types of storage attached).  You may do this by setting the `TMPDIR` environment variable to the path of writable directory on such a mountpoint (or use `sort -T directory`).

Comment: Note that GNU `sort` works in parallel by default, so no need to specify `--parallel` unless you want to use fewer threads than CPU cores or more than 8 ones. It doesn't make sense to use disk storage on memory. temporary storage is used to offload memory. No need to offload in the first place if it's to still go to memory.

Comment: I find that GNU `sort` (8.28) seems to use additional threads (with or without `--parallel`) only for regular files (not for pipes nor sockets, not even block devices)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I can't see an explicit test for this in the source for 8.29.

Comment: It seems it has to do with how the data is read and how the threads are spawned. It needs at least 128*1024 lines in an input buffer to spawn a new thread, and it seems that  for non-regular files (where `find` doesn't know the size of the file), it never happens unless you raise the `-S` size above some threshold. 10M is not enough 100M seems to be enough for the output of `seq`. I've not looked in details.

Answer (score 1):

This is faster for me. YMMV (it definitely depends on how many duplicates there are):

```
parallel --lb --pipepart --block 15m -a /tmp/big.file 'sort | uniq -c' |
  awk '{ count[$2] += $1 } END { for(elem in count) print count[elem], elem }' |
  sort -n
```

Comment: Thanks Ole! always cool to stumble upon advice from such a legend.

Comment: There is something strange about the performance of this method. it does not seem to slam the CPU constantly, there is dips in performance. https://imgur.com/a/2JdqI1u

Comment: @DoNotTrackMe What does your disk I/O look like? If the CPU is waiting for disk I/O it will explain the dips.