# Sort column by duplicates and keep the first occurrence

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file that is as follows

```
1:A
2:B
3:A
```

I need the output to be:

```
1:A
2:B
```

As the third entries second column contains A, like the first entry does, it removes it. Also it needs to be case sensitive.

It's an extremely large file so time saving would be nice.

I have tried this but it seems to only print the unique lines

```
sort -u -t':' -k3,3 file
```

Comment: With `-k3,3` you're telling sort to sort by the 3rd field when the input has 2 fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using `sort`

As Ed states in his [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667694/sort-column-by-duplicates-and-keep-the-first-occurrence/667696#comment1257930_667694), your `sort` command is sorting on the third field, when in fact you only have two fields (the `:` is the field separator). So to fix it, replace `3` with `2` for the key.

However, then the original record order in the source file gets messed up, when the records being sorted by their key value rather than by the line/record number:

```
$ sort -u -t':' -k2,2 test.txt 
1:A
2:B
6:C
5:a
4:b
$
```

Which is probably *not* what you want. Nevertheless, this is easily fixed by piping the output through `sort` again:

```
$ sort -u -t':' -k2,2 test.txt | sort 
1:A
2:B
4:b
5:a
6:C
$
```

**Note**: As you say that you have a large file then, in order to speed things up, you may want to consider using the `--parallel` flag<sup>1</sup>:

```
sort --parallel=<n> -u -t':' -k2,2 test.txt | sort --parallel=<n>
```

When `<n>` is the number of cores that you have available.

#### Using `awk`

Expanding upon your example file, if the original data is in a file called `test.txt`, like this:

```
1:A
2:B
3:A
4:b
5:a
6:C
```

and, again, treating the `:` as a field separator, then you could use `awk`<sup>2</sup>.

For example this  line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{if (!seen[$2]++)print $0}' test.txt
```

Gives the following result:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{if (!seen[$2]++)print $0}' test.txt 
1:A
2:B
4:b
5:a
6:C
$
```

---

You can see how this works by looking at the logic, using

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print !seen[$2]++}' test.txt 
1
1
0
1
1
1
$
```

- First, the field separator is specified with `FS=":"`.
- Second, the negation operator gives a "true" result for a second field entry that hasn't *yet* been seen.
- Finally, the `print $0` prints the whole record, i.e. the current line.

---

Putting this into a shell script<sup>3</sup> rather than an `awk` script gives:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -F':' '
  (!seen[$2]++) {
    print $0
  }
' "$1"
```

**References**:

<sup>1</sup> This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120100/97255) to [How to sort big files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120096/97255)

<sup>2</sup> This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439540/97255) to [Keeping unique rows based on information from 2 of three columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439539/97255)

<sup>3</sup> This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/4424636) to [Specify other flags in awk script header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61000804/4424636)